# Como fazer um slide apenas texto no bootstrap

Tags: carousel, texto

Gostaria que esse elemento virasse slider, mas quero apenas o texto e a imagem desse jeito, não consigo fazer
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ta ficando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS

```css
.carousel-title{
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  transition: color .26s ease-in-out;
}
.carousel-text{
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  transition: color .26s ease-in-out;
  text-align: justify;
}
.product-slide{
background: url(../image/background-page.png);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
padding: 20px 0px;
  }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Overlay menu</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Source+Sans+Pro:200i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: O Bootstrap já tem um componente prontinho pra vc usar, é só pegar na documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ não deu para entender sua úvida direito

Comment: Sim eu sei, mas eu queria que o slide pasasse igualzinho eu coloquei no print, sem imagens grandes, queria que o slide aparecesse o row, saca? Imagem pequena do lado o texto, só isso.

Comment: Cara é só colocar uma row/col dentro da estrutura do Slidar, dentro do Slide 1 vc colocar uma row e duas col... Pelo que vc faleo seu problema não é o slider, e sim como colocar uma imagem do lado esquerdo e um testo do lado direito, para isso vc pode usar a classe `pull-left` na imagem...

Comment: Até consegui mas apareceu outro problema https://prnt.sc/rc3tap , nao fica como a imagem do próprio topico

Comment: Refiz o topico explicando melhor e com o novo codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta seguir o código do carousel padrão do Bootstrap getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel  e colocar uma imagem e o texto dentro do `<div class="carousel-item">` sendo que na imagem vc coloca a classe `float-left` para ela ficar a esquerda do texto

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg-primary">
  
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="float-left mr-4" src="https://unsplash.it/50/200" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste amet alias maxime molestias provident ducimus perferendis dignissimos corrupti! Possimus, quasi! Sequi rerum asperiores tempore, consequatur at aperiam molestias in?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="float-left mr-4" src="https://unsplash.it/55/200" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste amet alias maxime molestias provident ducimus perferendis dignissimos corrupti! Possimus, quasi! Sequi rerum asperiores tempore, consequatur at aperiam molestias in?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="float-left mr-4" src="https://unsplash.it/60/200" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste amet alias maxime molestias provident ducimus perferendis dignissimos corrupti! Possimus, quasi! Sequi rerum asperiores tempore, consequatur at aperiam molestias in?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```